# web loadable 80x80 thumbnail images - best format choice if compression is done on the server

Tags: iphone, ios, png, thumbnails, jpeg

I've read many of the png vs. jpg threads here and elsewhere. I didn't find this aspect covered for small images that are downloaded from a server.

A short recap:

1. Xcode optimizes png images that are delivered with the app bundle in a way that they are optimized for the iOS hardware ("png magic")
2. png images support transparency (which I don't need)
3. png is the better choice from graphics, jpg for pictures (we have pictures)

I'm building an app that periodically downloads feeds that contain links to thumbnail images (size 80x80). These images are presented side by side the text content in a tableview. I can influence which format is used (jpg, png) on the server side.

If I use an uncompressed png format, it will have about 17k size for one image. This is quite large. And since this png doesn't use the "png magic" of Xcode, the iPhone still might need quite some cpu to get them into the table view compared to an "Xcode prepared" png.
The same image as a compressed jpg is only 3k which is great.

Question: are there lab comparisons that show the real world performance of these 2 formats?

Another one: has anyone used jpgs of a similar size (80x80, 3k) successfully in a table-view?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "lab comparisons"? PNG is going to do better with flat colors -- it uses variations on run-length and dictionary encoding as I understand. JPEG will be better with images containing subtle gradients, and loses data mostly in jumps in luminosity which are hard for the human eye to see. "Better" here refers only to file size. It sounds like you would want JPEGs here.

Comment: Thanks. With lab comparisons I mean like creating 50 images in both formats and loading them into a table-view (png non optimized). How long does either take? Is scrolling of the table view fine also with jpg? I would prefer jpg because the transfer time will be shorter, but will they slow down the table-view? Sorry if I didn't make my question clear.

Comment: Other than differences in speed of decoding the images, they won't affect speed of scrolling. Once the image is displayed, it is decoded, meaning it is now raw uncompressed 24-bit color. Its original format is irrelevant. I suspect PNG decodes faster than JPEG, but haven't done any tests to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this is an invaluable information! However, I've decided to do the lab for our use case in my spare time. I'll keep this thread tracked on what I find.

Comment: First results: there seems to be no feelable performance hit so far. I'havn't gone through the Instruments stack for numbers.

Comment: I case this will causes problems, it would still be possible to download the jpg's once, convert them into png representations and save them in that format for reuse. Is there something wrong about that idea?

Comment: @brainray Yes. You should read up on these formats, but in a nutshell -- JPEGs compress photos very well whereas PNGs are more suited to art with lots of solid colors. Choosing the wrong format will explode your file sizes and may cause visible artifacts. JPEGs are lossy but the lossiness tends to be things that human eyes don't see.

Comment: just for the record: in the end I used jpg and didn't regret it. Scrolling though hundreds of different tableview cells was very fluently on the iPhone 4, and still very acceptable on a iPhone 3GS.